# Spring boot running fine, but not its Jar?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I've build this application using in-memory H2 database.
If I run *mvn spring-boot:run* it starts Tomcat on port 8081 and I can use the url *localhost:8081/Patients* just fine and able to interact with the database.
If I run *mvn package* and then *java -jar* the jar file from */target*, it starts Tomcat on port 8081 and the above url returns 404. The message shown is as if it's not finding the resource, which is a jsp file.

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   /Patients/WEB-INF/views/patient/welcome.jsp

I'm trying to build this application that can live on it's on, but not sure what I'm missing.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Paulo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Patients</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Patients</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
              <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.properties

```
#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pauloaraujo?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.username = root
#spring.datasource.password = pauloaraujo
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
server.port=8081
server.contextPath=/Patients
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

EDIT:

I learned that Tomcat doesn't hand executable jars with JSPs, then I changed my packaging to WAR.
I ran *java -jar mywar.war* and the result is that Tomcat is on port 8080 and the message is

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the logs, if you have any, otherwise add logback, so you will have logs.

Couple of things I noticed:

- remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from Tomcat starter and from tomcat-embed-jasper, these are needed with compile scope.
- Remove the version number from your Spring dependencies, the parent is there to provide the versions.
- Tomcat is not able to handle [jsps in runnable jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations). Read up on "executable war" (you need war packaging).

Comment: I updated my question, because I was wrong about the port and message. The url is not finding the jsp file.

Comment: Oh. Then I should create a WAR file and instruct the other person to upload it to Eclipse, for example?

Comment: @Paul Traditionally war files should be handled by servlet or application container (like a standalone Tomcat, Jetty, etc...). But in Spring Boot you can create an executable war as well, just change `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your pom.xml, and you can run with with `java -jar somewar.war`. Eclipse is/was never needed to run the production application. The other points are also important, though they are probably not the root cause of your problem now.

Comment: I changed to war packaging, but there's a new problem. I included in my original question.

Comment: @Paul Remove the `<resources>` section from your pom.xml and it should work.

Comment: Omg. It worked. It's alive (lul). Thank you!!!!! (lessons learned, "read the documentation"?)